Can I use raw scores of MMPI 2 in logistic regression?
I'm trying to prove whether the MMPI code types of the participants predicts Ego types (Low or Average) and Low Self-Esteem Levels (either high or average). The data for the Ego type and LSE levels came from the interpretation of the supplementary scales of MMPI 2. The premises of the question being answered is whether there is a relationship between the code types of the participants and their ego type and LSE levels. How should I treat the raw scores of the code type? Can I use it as is in logistic regression and dummy code the ego type and LSE levels?

Peter Flom already gave a good answer, but also, you should explain what the code types, Ego types, supplementary scales etc. are exactly. I think most people (here and in general) are not familiar with the MMPI instrument.

Lots of issues here.
First "prove" is too strong a word. You can find evidence of something, but proving things with statistics in what will have to be an observational study is not possible without a lot of other things. "Correlation does not imply causation."
Second, you appear to be dichotomizing numeric scales (self-esteem and maybe others). This is almost never a good idea.
Third, it's not clear, but "code type" appears to be a nominal variable. That's fine. It also appears to be the independent variable.
Fourth, the type of regression to use is chosen based  on the dependent variable. You have "ego type low vs. average".  Is ego type a numeric scale? If so, I would leave it as such and start with OLS regression. If it is an ordinal scale, why are you not including "high"  (I'm assuming there is a "high") and then use ordinal logistic?  Your other DV is self-esteem. I am pretty sure this is a numeric scale. So, I would leave it as such.  You might want to use splines to explore nonlinearity.
Fifth, why MMPI-2? The MMPI-3 has been out for several years.
Finally, given all the above, you might want to consider hiring a statistician, or collaborating with one.
